# Canvas implementation on different images

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

i'm using next sample in my code: http://jsfiddle.net/8wegxnz3/

```
var lasticon;
$(function () {
    $('.icon').click(function () {
        if (lasticon != this.id) {
            $('#' + lasticon + 'L').toggle();
            lasticon = this.id;
        } else {
            lasticon = null;
        }
        $('#' + this.id + 'L').toggle();

    });
});

.iconL {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}

var lasticon;
$(function () {
    $('.icon').click(function () {
        if (lasticon != this.id) {
            $('#' + lasticon + 'L').toggle();
            lasticon = this.id;
        } else {
            lasticon = null;
        }
        $('#' + this.id + 'L').toggle();

    });
});
```

What I want is to implement the next solution to my first code I found in the next jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LAS8L/

I have make some test and tried to implement it to my code, but nothing happens.

I would like to be able to resize and move the second image that appear when clicking the first image. So you could for example click the "e-mail icon" and then resize the second icon that appears.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really easy. But here are some starting points:

- read [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/) tutorial about image cropping and resizing with canvas
- see my [jsBIN](http://codepen.io/janhommes/pen/eaKsA) as an example implementation. You can copy the code, add an image to the `<img class="resize-image" src="img/YOURIMAGE.jpg" alt="image for resizing">` tag and you can resize and crop it
- alternative you can use [this jquery plugin](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)

Basically you doing the following:

1. load the original image into the DOM
2. Resize and crop your image with Javascript to display the cropping result to your user.
3. load the original image into a canvas
4. crop & resize the image in the canvas with the data returned by the user (Step 2)
5. extract the image with the toDataURL function from the canvas
6. Send the DataURL to a web service that saves this information to your webs erver hard disk.